Fetch hash of Bazel output artifact with minimal building and fetching?
I would like to determine the hash of a Bazel target artifact, with the minimal amount of building and fetching.
This is in order to build a flow like:

Fetch artifact hash for a given target
Check if the hash has never been seen before
If so, build the artifact

This is necessary to avoid building / fetching artifacts wherever possible, since they can be very large.
What Bazel commands are available to achieve step (1) ?

Bazel should already be doing the minimal work by default using its in-memory incrementality engine and action cache. Do you have a repro case to show that this is not the case?
Otherwise, remote caching might be what you're looking for, to store the build artifacts off-host. You can even use an on-disk cache if you don't want to set up a dedicated backend.

I want to ask Bazel "Give me the hash of this target output, doing minimal work". The only way I am aware of to do this is to build the target fully (which may be a big build / download from cache) and then hash it myself. In theory, Bazel may have the hash already (in cache) and not need to build anything.

You can achieve this with a bit of boiler-plate and some orchestration outside of Bazel.
First, create a custom rule for computing the hash of a given target:
def _impl(ctx):
  ctx.actions.run_shell(
    outputs = [ctx.outputs.sha256],
    inputs = [ctx.file.src],
    use_default_shell_env = True,
    command = "sha256sum {} | cut -d ' ' -f 1 > {}".format(ctx.file.src.path, ctx.outputs.sha256.path),
  )

  return DefaultInfo(files = depset([ctx.outputs.sha256]))

_hash = rule(
  implementation = _impl,
  attrs = {
    "src": attr.label(mandatory = True, allow_single_file = True),
    "sha256": attr.output(),
  },
)

def hash(**kwargs):
  name = kwargs["name"]
  _hash(
    sha256 = "%s.sha256" % name,
    **kwargs
  )

Now apply this rule to the target you want to hash:
hash(
  name = "big_thing_hash",
  src = ":big_thing",
)

To perform an ordinary test build, enable Build Without Bytes flags and do:
bazel build :big_thing_hash

This will ensure :big_thing and :big_thing_hash have been built and populated into the cache, with minimal fetching. :big_thing_hash, which is only a tiny text file, will be present in bazel-bin.
Compare the output to previous hashes.
cat $(bazel cquery :big_thing_hash --output=files)

If the hash has not been seen before, build the artifact:
bazel build :big_thing

It would be great if this were a built-in feature of Bazel!
